# Mongodb Remote Server with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I wanted to know a connection format to connect to a local server using an IP. I used the following but no luck

```
mongodb//x.x.x.x:27017
```

And also do I need to have configuration in my server to allow connection from remote machines? Thanks. I really aprecciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the colon.  It's `mongodb://x.x.x.x:27017`.  27017 is the default port so you can omit that if you wish.  And, of course you need to open port 27017 on the other side.

Comment: Oh thanks that's actually I used, and I also keep running the mongod instance on my remote server but no luck. As I connect to the server it gave me this error. `Unable to connect to server x.x.x.x:27017: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond x.x.x.x:27017`. Is there something wrong in my end? Or in the remote server?

Comment: I also tried to connect using the mongo shell but still the connection failed: --> `mongo x.x.x.x`    >`Javascript Execution Failed: Error: couldn't connect to server x.x.x.x:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L114 exception: connect failed`

Comment: Anyway, I have authentication in my server. Do I have to use the username and the password the same as the one I used in doing REMOTE DESKTOP CONNECTION? I use the following in the shell `mongo Admin:mypassword@x.x.x.x` but no luck.